# Arrangement views in Layout

Tags: android, xml

I'm sorry for this question but i'm confused about it.

I have two buttons like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2" />
```

And in the Android code :

```
a  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
b  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //my code
    }
});
```

When I change the arrangement of the buttons to look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1" />
```

then the `a` button doesn't listen. The listener is associated to the `b` button!

Comment: Are you sure that all you're doing in change the order of the two <Button> tags in the XML? Or are you also making changes in the Java code?

Comment: In which layout you have these buttons?

Comment: provide parent layout of these buttons' it is not enough for giving proper answer why that button is not working

Comment: thanx for correct the question,yes I just change the xml

Comment: Check if by mistake you changed ID? Clean build project and rerun.

Comment: Solved issue? @user2239196

Answer (score 0):

You might have changed the ids while rearranging.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
/>
```

Check that, and clean + build project. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

When you rearrange the buttons the listener will move to the second button,

So when you will click the button with text = 2 you wouldn't get anything,
and when you click the button with text = 1 you will have the action assigned.

Otherwise in the fist case, the 2 button will respond and not the 1

Comment: I am not saying that it does not,

Comment: yea, sorry, it was cause I misunderstood ur answer the first time I read it, but still your answer doesn't answer his question, in all cases the 1 button must respond, rearranging the buttons must not affect anything, I think he forgot something that misses with his code